# Select from database order by count of records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
Tags:

id | tag   | news_id
---+-------+---------
1  | tag1  | 1
2  | tag2  | 1
3  | tag3  | 1
4  | tag1  | 2
5  | tag2  | 2
6  | tag3  | 3
7  | tag1  | 3
8  | tag3  | 4
9  | tag1  | 5
```

How can I select `tag` field but order by count of tags ?
I mean an output like this:

```
tag1,tag3,tag2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output, use **GROUP_CONCAT()** along with **GROUP BY** to concatenate rows by comma. Like this,

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag SEPARATOR ',') AS str_tags
FROM
(
   SELECT tag
   FROM tags
   GROUP BY tag
   ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC
) AS t;
```

Where the sub query returns the output like this:

```
 tag
-----
 tag1
 tag3
 tag2
```

And GROUP_CONCAT() in outer query, concatenates the resulting rows by comma:

```
tag1,tag3,tag2
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT t.tag
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.tag
ORDER BY COUNT(t.tag) desc
```